# How can I update state with the new comment list in Flutter after calling getPosts() function from Firebase?

Tags: flutter

i have a button when i press on it adds comment on a list and update the instance recElement to add to it the new comment

after that I called getPosts function from firebase to get the new reclamation list but it don't want to set the state
when I update the response(onPressAsAdmin function) with the same way it works but with comment list it won't

this is the functions

```
 void onPressAsAdmin() {
    setState(() {
      reponseTextController.text.length != 0
          ? widget.recElement.reponse = reponseTextController.text
          : {};
      widget.recElement.etat = typeSelected;

      Provider.of<RecProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateRec(widget.recElement);
      Provider.of<RecProvider>(context, listen: false).getPosts();
      // sendEmail();
    });
  }

  void addComment() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm').format(now);

    Map<String, dynamic> comment = {
      'ownerMail':
          Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false).currentUser!.email ??
              "mail",
      'text': reponseTextController.text,
      'time': formattedDate,
    };

    Provider.of<RecProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .updateData(widget.recElement, comment);
    // sendEmail();

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        widget.recElement.comments;
        Provider.of<RecProvider>(context, listen: false).getPosts();
      });
    }
  }
```

and this is some of the the code of the view

```
 widget.recElement.reponse != null
                        ? Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "response:" +
                                  widget.recElement.reponse.toString(),
                            ),
                          )
                        : SizedBox(),
                    //if statmenet could be here
                    widget.recElement.img == null ||
                            widget.recElement.img!.isEmpty
                        ? Text("PlaceHolder image")
                        : ImageGrid(
                            imageUrls: widget.recElement.img!.toList(),
                          ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 7.0,
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Spacer(),
                          Text(
                            ' comments(' +
                                widget.recElement.comments.length.toString() +
                                ')',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              autofocus: true,
                              controller: reponseTextController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText:
                                      currentItemSelectedFromAsAdmin == "user"
                                          ? 'comment'
                                          : 'response'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 16.0,
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (currentItemSelectedFromAsAdmin == "user") {
                                addComment();
                              } else
                                onPressAsAdmin();
                            },
                            child: Text('save'),
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```